# Combine find-chmod for directories and find-chmod for regular files

Tags: find, chmod

I have these commands:

```
find /var/www/html/* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/* -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I understood from Stephen Kitt's answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184784/nix-cron-daily-and-weekly-scripts-for-a-minimal-nginx-server-environment) that I could combine them this way:

```
find /var/www/html/* -exec chmod a-x,a=rX,u+w {} \+
```

These `chmod` arguments are less comfortable for me to read, especially in the `find` syntax (I've yet to become familiar with the nix meaning of the combos like `a-x`, `a=rX`, and `u+w` and I don't have the time and peacefulness of mind to learn it in a serious way in the coming days).

Is it possible to use numbers there? If not, there might be a bit more comfortable way to unite the two commands even if a tiny bit longer than the particular one proposed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you should use whatever you feel comfortable with; so

```
find /var/www/html/* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \+
find /var/www/html/* -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \+
```

is fine (`\+` instead of `\;`).

The `a-x,a=rX,u+w` [`chmod` arguments](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) (see also [the POSIX specification for `chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html)) mean respectively:

- clear the execute bits for everyone (`a-x`),
- set the permissions for everyone (`a=`) to

  - read (`r`),
  - executable if directory or executable (`X`),
- add the writable bit for the owner (`u+w`).

The conditional part (executable if directory or executable) can’t be represented numerically.

The purpose of the sequential `-x` and `=rX` is to ensure that only directories have the execute bit set: since the execute bits are cleared, `X` can only match directories, not files with their execute bit set.

It occurs to me that you don’t need `find` at all here:

```
chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w /var/www/html/*
```

will apply the same changes using `chmod` only.