# xargs + chmod - file or directory not found

Tags: permissions, find, pipe, chmod, xargs

I am trying to recursively change the permission of all files and directories in my project.

I found a [post on the magento forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/403-forbidden-error-with-magento-ce-1-9-1-1/m-p/7351/highlight/true#M1038) saying that I can use these commands:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media
```

It worked for `find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755`.

The command `find ./ -type f` returned a lot of files, but I get `chmod: access to 'fileXY.html' not possible: file or directory not found` on all files, if I execute `find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644`.

How can I solve this?

PS: I know that he recommended to use 777 permission for my var and media folder, which is a security risk, but what else should we use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m guessing you’re running into files whose names contain characters which cause `xargs` to split them up, *e.g.* whitespace. To resolve that, assuming you’re using a version of `find` and `xargs` which support the appropriate options (which originated in the GNU variants, and aren’t specified by POSIX), you should use the following commands instead:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

or better yet,

```
chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w .
```

which has the advantages of being shorter, using only one process, and being supported by [POSIX `chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416393/86440) for details).

Your question on `media` and `var` is rather broad, if you’re interested in specific answers I suggest you ask it as a separate question with more information on what your use of the directories is.

Comment: Or execute `chmod` from `find` directly with `-exec chmod 644 {} +`.

Comment: Since the question isn't tagged with the Linux tag, in the interest of not confusing non-Linux users who find this page I'd note that `print0` is a GNU platform-specific extension and not available to [the POSIX standard `find` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  LIkewise with the `-0` option to [xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html).

Comment: @Andrew done; note that the `chmod` standalone variant *is* POSIX-compliant (but I’m not sure it’s supported on macOS, despite the latter being certified Unix).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

this is the canonical portable solution that deals even with newlines in file names.