# What is the meaning of chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w?

Tags: chmod

What is the meaning of `chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w`?

`chmod` changes file permissions, `-R` makes it be done recursively but what are:

- `a-x`
- `a=rX`
- `u+w`

here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a-x` clears the executable bit for everyone (user, group, other).

`a=rX` sets the read bit for everyone, and the executable bit on directories; see [What is a capital X in posix / chmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416877/86440) for details. It clears all other bits. (This *can’t* be combined with `a-x`, because `X` here would set the executable bit for any non-directory with an executable bit set too; applying `a-x` first ensures that only directories get their executable bit set.)

`u+w` sets the write bit for the user.

The result is that all directories end up with 755 permissions, and everything else with 644 permissions. Here are a few examples:

| Step | Regular file | Executable | Directory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `a-x` | `??-??-??-` | `??-??-??-` | `??-??-??-` |
| `a=rX` | `r--r--r--` | `r--r--r--` | `r-xr-xr-x` |
| `u+w` | `rw-r--r--` | `rw-r--r--` | `rwxr-xr-x` |

If we leave out the `a-x` step, one of the executable’s `x` bits would be set (otherwise it wouldn’t be an executable), and the `a=rX` step would handle it like a directory.

If you prefer reasoning in terms of “read, write, execute”, then `a=r,u+w,a+X` might be easier to understand:

| Step | Regular file | Executable | Directory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `a=r` | `r--r--r--` | `r--r--r--` | `r--r--r--` |
| `u+w` | `rw-r--r--` | `rw-r--r--` | `rw-r--r--` |
| `a+X` | `r--r--r--` | `r--r--r--` | `rwxr-xr-x` |

This would also work better on at least some versions of macOS where `X` is only recognised with `+` operations, not `=`.

See [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for more context, and [Combine find-chmod for directories and find-chmod for regular files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416392/86440) for other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Those are a symbolic way of specifying permissions, so you don't have to remember the value of each and be able to add those together.

`,` is just a separator, allowing you to specify multiple permissions (changes to permissions), in your example there are three separate permissions `a-x`, `a=rX` and `u+w`.

Each permission start with a specification of who it applies to, that can be either *u*ser, *g*roup, *o*thers (be careful not to think o is for owner) or *all* (or a compositions of those, you can use e.g. `ug` to specify something for both user and group.
Then follows either a `+`, `-` or `=`, to say whether you want to add permissions, remove permissions or specify permissions precisely.
Last is the actual permissions, the most common are *r*ead, *w*rite and e*x*ecute (meaning search for directories), but there is also characters for setuid/setgid (*s*), stickiness (*t*), and *X* that is described in the man page as "execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user".

In your example `a-x` means remove (*`-`*) the e*x*ecute permission for everybody (*a*ll), and `u+w` means add (*`+`*) *w*rite permission for the *u*ser. Lastly (except that I have explained them in a different order from how they were given = how they are applied) the permissions for everybody (*a*ll) are set to read and execute (on directories, e*x*excute on files were removed before).

Note that if they were evaluted in the order I've explained them `u+w` would be pointless, as a rule for everybody follows - but I've explained them in a different order from given to get the most complicated (the 'X') last.